# Fabricjs text styling not asynchronous

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

In an app I'm building I'm using fabricjs to render text onto a canvas. I want to use a button to make that text bold but there seems to be a problem with how it gets rendered. Instead of it happening asynchronously or at the same time, I have to click outside the selected text before anything happens. I don't really know how to explain it too well, so I reproduced the challenge I'm having in a CodePen.
https://codepen.io/JojoDuke/pen/wvrgjaw

**Code**

```
//HTML
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="100"></canvas>
<button id="boldBtn">Make Bold</button>
<button id="normalBtn">Make Normal</button>

//Script
const boldBtn = document.getElementById('boldBtn');
const normalBtn = document.getElementById('normalBtn');
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {
  backgroundColor: 'grey',
});

const text = new fabric.IText('Type text here', { 
                      left: 100, 
                      top: 10,
                    });

canvas.add(text);
canvas.renderAll();

boldBtn.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  text.fontWeight = await "bold";
})

normalBtn.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  text.fontWeight = await "normal";
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jeremy mentioned you can add the element to the canvas during the asycronous event or force the canvas to do a re-render of all elements contained within.

Example:

```
boldBtn.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  text.fontWeight = await "bold";
  canvas.renderAll();
})

normalBtn.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  text.fontWeight = await "normal";
  canvas.renderAll();
})
```

Working codepen: https://codepen.io/carve-the-looper/pen/VwMbxpX